# render_to_string() complains of a NoneType error

Tags: python, django

So I'm testing my code in `python manage.py shell`, however I'm getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`.

Here's what I've done in the app's `models.py`:

```
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
import mandrill
```

<...>

```
def email_invoice(self):
    dated, amount, subtenant = self.dated, self.amount, self.subtenant.name
    net_amount = self.amount / 1.13
    hst = amount - net_amount
    context = {
                'date': dated,
                'amount': amount,
                'net_amount': net_amount,
                'hst': hst,
                'subtenant': subtenant
    }
    msg_html = render_to_string('email/invoice.html', context)
    message = {
                'to': [{'email': '<left out>',
                        'name': '<left out>',
                        'type': 'to'}],
                'subject': 'Testing',
                'html': msg_html,
                'from_email': '<left out>',
                'from_name': '<left out>'
    }
    try:
        mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill('<left out>')
        result = mandrill_client.messages.send(message=message)
    except mandrill.Error as e:
        print('A mandrill error occurred: %s - %s' % (e.__class__, e))
        raise
```

The traceback seems to suggest that the issue is with `render_to_string()`, but I don't see what I've done wrong with its implementation: I tested that the template exists (it's an email template) in the shell. In fact, `render_to_string('email/invoice.html')` without a context works fine. The issue is with the context.

I tried playing around with a simple dict in the shell, like `context = {'hst': 123}` and that works too. For some reason it doesn't like my dict above, and complains of a NoneType. I individually checked each object field to make sure it exists and that it returns a value in the shell.

Any idea where this NoneType is coming from?

EDIT: Here is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/gcap/rental/models.py", line 41, in email_invoice
    msg_html = render_to_string('email/invoice.html', context)
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 99, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 74, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 92, in render
    output = force_text(output)
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 90, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s)
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djmoney/models/fields.py", line 133, in __str__
    locale = self.__get_current_locale()
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djmoney/models/fields.py", line 103, in __get_current_locale
    locale = translation.to_locale(translation.get_language())
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 185, in to_locale
    return _trans.to_locale(language)
  File "/Users/cyehia/Documents/Apps/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 75, in to_locale
    p = language.find('-')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Please, provide the full traceback

Comment: Added the traceback, thank you in advance!

Comment: `context` is a bad name for your dictionary passed to `render_to_string`. Since the third, optional argument from docs is called `context_instance` see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut)

Comment: Do you have a `LANGUAGE_CODE` in your settings?

Comment: Yes @AdrianGhiuta, it's currently set for `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PaulRooney, I've quickly tried changing the name of the variable to something else in the shell, if I pass a very simple dict it works regardless of whether I call it `c` or `context`. I'll try it in my code when I get back home though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with an [incompatibly between Django 1.8 and django-money](http://github.com/django-money/django-money/issues/118). I'd try manually activating a language with:

```
from django.utils.translation import activate 

def email_invoice(self):
    <....>
    activate('en')
    msg_html = render_to_string('email/invoice.html', context)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I'll keep a close eye on that incompatibility issue (or find another money module to work with...)